# Parsing XML with cElementTree

Tags: python, xml, xpath, celementtree

I have been tasked with re-writing some old XML parsing code to Python and I stumbled into the joy that is `cElementTree` and I love it because I can do so much in so few lines.

My experience level with `xpath` is not that extensive and this question is more about drilling further down the structure.

I have this in `test.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
   <ownershipDocument>
     <issue>
         <ic>0000030305</ic>
         <iname>DUCOMM</iname>
         <its>DCP</its>
     </issue>
     <ndt>
         <ndtran>
             <tc>
                 <tft>4</tft>
                 <tc>P</tc>
                 <esi>0</esi>
             </tc>
         </ndtran>
         <ndtran>
             <tc>
                 <tft>4</tft>
                 <tc>P</tc>
                 <esi>0</esi>
             </tc>
          </ndtran>
     </ndt>
 </ownershipDocument>
```

I wrote this script in Python :

```
import xml.etree.cElementTree as ET
tree = ET.parse('test.xml')
root = tree.getroot()
print root.tag
print root.attrib
for child in root:
    print(child.tag, child.attrib)

for issue in root.findall('issue'):
    ic = issue.find('ic').text
    iname= issue.find('iname').text
    print(ic,iname)
```

This gives me :

```
ownershipDocument
{}
('issue', {})
('ndt', {})
('0000030305', 'DUCOMM')
```

That successfully gets me the info I need in the "issue".

Problem is that I need to access multiple "ndtran" nodes ( in the "ndt" node ). While parsing I can extract the "tft", "tc" and "esi" values as groups but I need to iterate over each "tc" node, extract the "tft","tc","esi" values, insert them into a database and then move to the next "tc" node and do it again.

What I tried to use to iterate over each of these was this :

```
for tc in root.findall("./ndt/ndtran/tc"):
    tft = tc.find('tft').text
    tc = tc.find('tc').text
    esi = tc.find('esi').text
    print(tft,tc,esi)
```

This almost gets me there ( I think ) but it does give me an error.

```
esi = tc.find('esi').text
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'text'
```

I hope that makes sense. I believe what I am after is the DOM parsing methodology which is fine since these documents aren't that big.

I appreciate any advice or pointers in the right direction.

Comment: Try change `tc` from `for` by child item or anything name diferent to tc iter`for child in root.findall("./ndt/ndtran/tc")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were replacing value of `tc` attribute to be `string` in the previous line :

```
for tc in root.findall("./ndt/ndtran/tc"):
    tft = tc.find('tft').text
    tc = tc.find('tc').text
   #^^ use different variable name here
    esi = tc.find('esi').text
         #^^ at this point, `tc` is no longer referencing the outer <tc> elements
```

Interesting coincidence that `string` also has [`find()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.find) method which return `int` (`-1`) when the keyword is not found, hence the *'int' object has no attribute 'text'* error.